# Simple Scan crashes almost immediately upon start-up

Tags: dns, scanner, pthreads, documents

I'm using `simple-scan` on Debian and it is now always crashing.  It worked fine a few months ago.  I suspect that something got upgraded (I'm running `bullseye`) and broke things.

The output from `simple-scan` says:

```
simple-scan: thread-watch.c:165: avahi_threaded_poll_quit: Assertion `pthread_equal(pthread_self(), p->thread_id)' failed.
Abort
```

I tried running `ldd /usr/bin/simple-scan` to make sure all the packages associated with all the libraries are recent, including `libc6`.  I also tried running with `simple-scan -d`, but the debug output proved useless.  I also tried `strace /usr/sbin/simple-scan` to look at all the shared libraries that were being loaded and they all had recent versions.

I noticed that the `libavahi` shared libraries are loaded dynamically (i.e., not visible via `ldd`) by `simple-scan`.  So, I made sure that those were also recent.

I also tried `xsane`, but it has the same problem.

Perhaps unrelatedly, I see the following messages in my system log file:

```
avahi-daemon[1020220]: Too many clients, client request failed.
```

`scanimage` does not crash, but it fails in an unrelated way.

I am at my wit's end and don't know what else can be done.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to comment on your question, but as I don't have a reputation, I  cannot and therefore I'll do it in an answer.

I have got a similiar problem with simple-scan on debian bullseye since start of October 2022.
In my case I am able to start simple-scan. I then press the scan button. After a few seconds the scanner (Brother DCP) appears to start scanning. There is a little noise from the document feeder. But before anything is scanned, simple-scan crashes/closes.

xsane is working for me.

also simple-scan -d proved useless.

I just found out that scanning as superuser works.

**Update Jan 2, 2023:**
I wanted to scan today. Scanning as superuser (sudo simple-scan) does not work anymore.
There are no error messages in system logs or on the console.
xsane still works, but I find it cumbersome.

** 2nd Update Jan 2, 2023:**

I used `scanimage -L` to see a list of scanning devices:

```
device `brother4:net1;dev0' is a Brother *Brother_DCP_9020CDW DCP
device `airscan:w1:Brother DCP-9020CDW' is a WSD Brother DCP-9020CDW ip=192.168.x.y
```

simple-scan defaults to the first device. After choosing the second device simple-scan worked as a charm.
Unfortunately I never bothered checking the device dropdown menu before.

Comment: Ah.  It was on my todo list to try the superuser thing next.  I'll get back to you.  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I tried the root/superuser thing, but got the same result.  But, I figured out the problem.  I'll include that in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be "user error".  I saw that the following line in `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf’`:

```
clients-max=1
```

Not sure why this was added.  After I commented it out and restarted it via

```
sudo systemctl restart avahi-daemon.service
```

things started working again.